# Comparing values within an array to the arithmetic mean of the first and last numbers

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int count(float v[100],int n)
{
    int i,nr=0;
    float m;
    m=(v[0]+v[n-1])/2;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(v[i]>=m)
            nr++;
    return nr;
}
int main()
{
    int i,n,ok=0;
    float v[100];
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>v[i];
    if(v[0]==v[n-1])
        ok=1;
    if(count(v,n)==2 && ok==1)
        cout<<"YES";
    else
        if(ok==0 && count(v,n)==1)
            cout<<"YES";
        else
            cout<<"NO";
}
```

This program supposedly checks if the first and last numbers from within an array are the lowest values that are in that respective array. This is done , as the title states, by comparing the numbers to the arithmetic mean of the first and last numbers

The problem is, it doesn't. Whatever values I input, it only displays "NO" (meaning that these numbers are not the lowest). Gone through it a hundred times, but can't really figure out what's wrong...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For starters, `float`s don't do any good when compared using `==`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate...? Why would it not work, and what operator should I use instead ?

Comment: Whats your input data?  (The line @H2CO3 is referring to is `v[0] == v[n-1]`.  Floats aren't perfect representations, so there's some instances like `5.0 * 0.1 == 0.5` is false)

Comment: @GîdeiCodrin [It's a long story.](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: 6 for n, then 12 245 654 23 652 11

Comment: ... which correctly returns "NO".  `count` returns the number of datum that are `> (first + last) / 2`.  In your case, that number is `5`.  Maybe you should check if `count(v,n) == n-1`?

Answer (score 1):

The line `if(ok==0 && count(v,n)==1)` should be `if(ok==0 && count(v,n)== n-1)`.

If the first and last are not equal, but one of them is the lowest number, then `count(v,n)` will return `n-1`.

With your example data with 6 input: `12 245 654 23 652 11`.
(first + last) / 2 = 11.5
12, 245, 654, 23, and 652 are all greater than 11.5, so `count(v,n)` returns `5 (e.g. n-1)`, which indicates that "either the first of the last number is the lowest".

---

**edit:** The simplest solution would be fixing `count()` to check `if(v[i]<=m)` instead of `>=`.  That way it returns the quantity of datum that are less than (first+last)/2.  If first==last, it will return 2, if first!==last, it should return 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is fundamentally flawed and won't do what you want (check if the first and last numbers are the two lowest). Consider this array:

`2, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20`

Every element except the first is greater than the mean (`11`) but the last item is the *largest* not one of the smallest two.

I think the actual simplest way to solve this is to `partial_sort` the first two elements (in a temporary container if needed) and check if they match the first and last elements of the original data.

Comment: Altough I understand what the flaw was...I am unsure as to what partial_sort is, or how to do what you call "the simplest way"...could you explain/elaborate please?